# How to integrate paypal rest api in spring JPA application. ERROR CODE 400

Tags: java, spring, jpa, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

As per the java SDK provided [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK) , I created a new project and tried to integrate the codes to make paypal api calls. But when I run the application, it gives me error as :-

```
Error code : 401 with response : Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
```

Here is my controller class

```
package com.main.controller;

public class PaymentController{ 

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/JSON")

public Payment getString(){

    InputStream is = PaymentController.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/sdk_config.properties");
    try {
        PayPalResource.initConfig(is);
        System.out.println("initiialization done");
    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
        System.out.println("Paypal Rest Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }

    Map<String, String > map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("mode", "sandbox");
    String clientID = "AYDNebhrsuqiUKPU_ab-tCvGGVkzaxw2y4bIJFIl4rMuCW..........................";
    String clientSecret="ENgjkFRgy1yGhal0aobwdF8kLNglkDaDeDItLN-lgQJZV4W1FpNQ27g3FC...............";

    try {
        accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID, clientSecret,map).getAccessToken();
    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Cannot make the OAuthentication :" + e.getMessage());
    }

    Payment payment = createPayment();

    return payment;
}

public Payment createPayment(){

    Address billingAddress = new Address();
    billingAddress.setCity("Johnstown");
    billingAddress.setCountryCode("US");
    billingAddress.setLine1("52 N Main ST");
    billingAddress.setPostalCode("43210");
    billingAddress.setState("OH");

    CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();        
    creditCard.setBillingAddress(billingAddress);
    creditCard.setCvv2(111);
    creditCard.setExpireMonth(11);
    creditCard.setExpireYear(2018);
    creditCard.setFirstName("Joe");
    creditCard.setLastName("Shopper");
    creditCard.setNumber("5500005555555559");
    creditCard.setType("mastercard");

    Details details = new Details();
    details.setShipping("1");
    details.setSubtotal("5");
    details.setTax("1");

    Amount amount = new Amount();
    amount.setCurrency("USD");
    amount.setTotal("7");
    amount.setDetails(details);

    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setAmount(amount);
    transaction
            .setDescription("This is the payment transaction description.");


    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    transactions.add(transaction);

    FundingInstrument fundingInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
    fundingInstrument.setCreditCard(creditCard);  


    List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstrumentList = new ArrayList<FundingInstrument>();
    fundingInstrumentList.add(fundingInstrument);

    Payer payer = new Payer();
    payer.setFundingInstruments(fundingInstrumentList);
    payer.setPaymentMethod("credit_card");

    Payment payment = new Payment();
    payment.setIntent("sale");
    payment.setPayer(payer);
    payment.setTransactions(transactions);
    Payment createdPayment = null;
    try {
        String accessToken = GenerateAccessToken.getAccessToken();

        String realAccessToken = "A101.kPIsO7eGXhg420XIjnZmPboCS27CeDF6TZjVfGR31f6ja1IotK3e6U-E_k9MwOO5.....";


        /*
         * String requestId = Long.toString(System.nanoTime(); APIContext
         * apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken, requestId ));
         */

        createdPayment = payment.create(apiContext);

        System.out.println("Created payment with id = " + createdPayment.getId()
        + " and status = " + createdPayment.getState());
    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot make the payment from here: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return createdPayment;
}
```

}

UPDATE :- I have added `client_id` and `secret` authentication credentials and now I get is `400` error which is `Validation Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 is Unauthorized. So, at first you have to authorized and create authorized token. [Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/) is example how to create you first call.

> Make a /token call using your application's OAuth keys for the basic authentication values (the keys are the values of your client_id and secret). In the request body, set grant_type to client_credentials. When you run the command, PayPal generates and returns a new access token.

Add your token to your payment which you want to create.

Look at this line in this Sample: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/sample/FuturePaymentSample.java#L62

So use Sandbox and something like that:

```
Map<String, String> configurationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            configurationMap.put("mode", "sandbox");
            APIContext apiContext = new APIContext();
            apiContext.setConfigurationMap(configurationMap);
            tokeninfo = Tokeninfo.createFromAuthorizationCodeForFpp(apiContext, params);
            tokeninfo.setAccessToken(tokeninfo.getTokenType() + " " + tokeninfo.getAccessToken());
```

After that you should be able to call tokeninfo.getAccessToken() for creating payment.

Comment: I have found that error from  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/rest-errors/. But then I had provided a valid token like this :- 
`String realAccessToken = "A101.kPIsO7eGXhg420XIjnZmPboCS27CeDF6TZjVfGR31f6ja1IotK3e6U-E_k9MwOO5.....";`

Comment: And if you are following this their example https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK#to-make-an-api-call , it still doesnt work? I mean OAuthTokenCredential to obtain token from it.

Comment: I just used the codes that I have mentioned above in the post. Nothing more than that. And yes `sdk_config.properties` of course

Comment: Ok, so this is next step :) Are you able to get validation messages? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/#validation-issues

Comment: I get this error 
`Error code : 400 with response : {"name":"UNKNOWN_ERROR","message":"An unknown error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNKNOWN_ERROR","debug_id":"2a1d1adfa6466"}`

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/issues/134  they closed it due to inactivity, but there are few good points. Check your account, try different card.

Comment: So do I need a sandbox paypal account or a real account will do fine?

Comment: For testing and dev you should really use sandbox. You can hold your account informations and informations for token in separate file and dev it with them and when you will be ready to real production test, you just change these files. If it will be OK with sandbox, then you know that is everything OK and start using real account.

Comment: Why does paypal only allow to select US as a country. It wasn't the same time before.

Comment: I am sorry, but I dont know. Try PayPal discussion on github. But I think that it is because when you in developement stage, you are using sandbox which allow only US. Btw problem with creating payment is OK now?

Comment: @Hrabosh Yes Now I am able to make payments. When I check the Transactions in paypal, I get the transaction logs. But from where does the amount get deducted? I see amount updated in my facilitator account but still 9999.00 USD in my buyer account.

And I also noticed that having a valid credit card number will accept the payment even though there is 0 balance.

Comment: @viper Ok, I am happy for that. Unfortunately, I dont know or I dont remember this sandbox logic. You have to check theid docs or discussions. I think that they have mocked it. If you think that problem is solved, accept answer please.